# Why are my keyframes being deleted when I reload my linked rigify rig or reload my scene file?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, rigify, linked-data

I have linked a rig into my scene, applied library overrides and animated it in Pose Mode. When I reload the scene file or reload the link file (in Blender File section), all the animation keyframes are deleted.

I am using a rigify rig.
I have other rigify rigs in use which do not have this problem.
There are no keyframes in the linked rig file.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Best
Gary

Comment: I've solved it.

Comment: For those who are interested, there was an 'action' hidden in my rig file (I must have created it by mistake) which was interfering with the library override keyframes. I found it by routing through the Data API tab and then looking for it in the Action Editor. Once I unlinked it from my rig, it became Orphan Data. I deleted it from the file and now my rig keyframes as normal. Hurray!!

Comment: maybe write that as your own answer -> this is possible and wanted here

Comment: Ah, will do Chris! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, there was an 'action' hidden in my rig file (I must have created it by mistake) which was interfering with the library override keyframes in my animation scene file.

I found it by routing through the Data API tab and then looking for it in the Action Editor. Once I unlinked it from my rig, it became Orphan Data and I deleted it. Now my rig keyframes as normal. Hurray!!

Comment: thank you, same problem here and couldn't of solved it without this, but it isnt just the action editor any keyframes will interfere with the linked rig